# Working with Ruby and Databases [PostgreSQL]

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql

I'm not versed working with DBs, but everytime I'm getting data from the DB with `res = con.exec "SELECT * FROM #{table}"` and then `res.values` I get all the values as if they were strings, for example:

```
[["1", "2017-01-14", "f"]]
```

Can I get Dates as Dates, integers as integers, etc.? or do I have to parse everything?

EDIT: I'm using Ruby without Rails.

Comment: Are you using Rails, or a database adapter like `pg` directly?

Comment: No rails, pg directly with ruby.

Comment: what database do you use, what type has your date in your database ? date or string ?

Comment: In the example that I shown it was INTEGER, DATE, BOOLEAN, but everything shows as string in Ruby and I use postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for the PG gem](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg#type-casts) details how to handle basic typecasting:

```
conn.type_map_for_results = PG::BasicTypeMapForResults.new conn
conn.exec("select 1, now(), '{2,3}'::int[]").values
    # => [[1, 2014-09-21 20:51:56 +0200, [2, 3]]]
```